# Get Json objects and display them on page using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a dynamic URL (http://domain.com/getUsers.php?team=1) that if its manually accessed, returns some Json objects on the browser:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"George"},{"id":2,"name":"John"}]
```

*I dont have access to getUsers.php so, I cant edit this file.
*If I look at the source code of this file on my browser, I only get pure json objects without any other HTML related tags like title, body etc.

I would like to display all the json elements from into a drop-down menu on some other page(http://domain.com/index.html).

```
<form>
<select name="users">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">George</option>
<option value="2">John</option>

</select>
</form>
```

What is the best way to do this with Jquery?
What is the Jquery code that I need to put on my index.html page to retrieve and display the data?

Thank you SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the trick is to iterate over the JSON object you receive and create elements with it.

Here's an example of how you could do this (and here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ruv3M/)

```
    // This is to simulate the JSON you retrieved via an AJAX call
var people = [{"id":1,"name":"George"},{"id":2,"name":"John"}],
    // Save a reference to your list of users
    $userSelect = $( '#userlist' ).find( 'select' );

// Iterate over each item in the object of people you received
for ( person in people ) {
    // create an option for each person
    $( '<option />', {
        value: people[person].id,
        text: people[person].name
    })
        // Append it to your list
        .appendTo( $userSelect ); 
}
```

**Update:** The simplest way to make an AJAX call for JSON data is with `$.getJSON()`. ([Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/))

In your code, it would probably look something like this:

```
// Instead of '/echo/json/', you'd use your AJAX URL
$.getJSON( '/echo/json/', function( data ) {
    // Set data equal to our dummy people variable, since it's blank in this example
    // NOTE! This step would be unnecessary in real life, where data would already be your JSON
    data = people;

    // Iterate over each item in the object of people you received
    // Note: iteration should be inside this callback, so it doesn't fire till your
    // data has been returned.
    for ( person in people ) {
        // create an option for each person
        $( '<option />', {
            value: people[person].id,
            text: people[person].name
        })
            // Append it to your list
            .appendTo( $userSelect ); 
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B2YF5/3/

Comment: Hello Nate!
Thanks for your super quick reply!
This worked fine!
Do you have any idea how to retrieve the Json objects via the Ajax call?

Comment: Sharethefun: I've added to my answer above to try to answer your question about getting the JSON via AJAX. Hope it helps!

Comment: I have added <script type="text/javascript" >
$.getJSON( 'index.json', function( data ) {
     $userSelect = $( '#userlist' ).find( 'select' );
     data = people;
      for ( person in people ) {
        // create an option for each person
        $( '<option />', {
   value: people[person].id,
   text: people[person].name
 })
.appendTo( $userSelect ); }
});
</script> 
on my index.html but the page only displays an empty select field.

Can you see something missing here?
Thank you so much Nate!

Comment: It's pretty hard to debug something at this level in comments. Can you post a URL where you've got your code not working?

Comment: Yeah, we're getting into issues with cross-domain restrictions. For AJAX requests, you have to request a URL from the same domain for it to work. Otherwise, you need to use JSONP (if you can change the server response) or an AJAX proxy that uses a server-side script of some kind. Either one of these is a bit more involved than the scope of this question.